# What usb wifi adapter can be used to watch streamed movies without disconnecting every 10 mins?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I currently use a USB wifi adapter with chipset Realtek RTL8192SU.

It works with no extra drivers to install in Ubuntu 64 bit 11.04. Under a light load it works fine. But when trying to watch streamed movies, it stops every 10 minutes. I don't have to reconnect, I have to just press play again to start the movie where it left off.

In Windows 7 it works fine. In a different laptop I'm using the built in wifi with Ubuntu 11.04 and no disconnects at all. I really think this adapter just doesn't work as well in Ubuntu.

I would like to know what adapter you use that doesn't freeze up on you consistently under a heavy load.

Comment: I had trouble streaming Netflix for a long time it would stop and load to where you just couldn't possibly watch the movies. I went to HHGregg and bought the a Sony USB adapter model#UWA-BR100. It works almost 100% of the time. No more loading. It was pretty expensive, but it works like a charm !! I leave it plugged into my Sony Bravia TV that I use to stream Netflix. I hope this is helpful to all having problems streaming.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest upgrading Ubuntu and seeing if that solves your problem as I believe it will. However if you are not wanting to do this, I beleive that a bugs relates to you and some steps in the link provided can help your issue.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/realtek-rtl8192su-ubuntu-driver-fix

Also, If this does not fix your problem, you should update to 12.04

Comment: Thanks I already tried the link above, that link allowed the wifi adapter to work.  I'll try upgrading to 12.04 to see if that helps.

Comment: I have the same chip set and its working good on 12.04 lts

Comment: You are welcome, please mark this as the correct answer then. :)